Why does Jesus tell the Jews to follow the Pharisees teaching while elsewhere He speaks of them creating unnecessary rules?
In Matthew 23:2, Jesus tells the Jews to: 'be careful to do everything they tell you to do', while elsewhere He speaks of them creating unnecessary or unuseful guidance or indeed condemning Jesus for actions that should not be condemned like healing others on the Sabbath?
Does their overly strict outlook and unnecessary tradition invalidate Matthew 23:2, 3?

“The scribes and Pharisees sit in Moses’ seat. So practice and
observe everything they tell you. But do not do what they do, for they
do not practice what they preach.


The answer to this question is provided by Jesus' explanation contained in the rest of the same chapter, Matt 23.
That is, to their credit, the Pharisees were encouraging people to keep the moral laws contained in the Torah - a very good thing.
BUT

Matt 23:3b - ... they do not practice what they preach.

Jesus then proceeds to document what they do that is so reprehensible:

V4: They tie up heavy, burdensome loads and lay them on men’s shoulders, but they themselves are not willing to lift a finger to move them.
V5: All their deeds are done for men to see. They broaden their phylacteries and lengthen their tassels. They love the places of honor at banquets, the chief seats in the synagogues, the greetings in the marketplaces, and the title of ‘Rabbi’ by which they are addressed. [None of these things are contained in the Torah.]
V13: You shut the kingdom of heaven in men’s faces. You yourselves do not enter, nor will you let in those who wish to enter.
V15: You traverse land and sea to win a single convert, and when he becomes one, you make him twice as much a son of hell as you are.
V16: You say, ‘If anyone swears by the temple, it means nothing; but if anyone swears by the gold of the temple, he is bound by his oath.’ [This was a facade of righteousness to extort more money for themselves.]
V23: You pay tithes of mint, dill, and cumin. But you have disregarded the weightier matters of the law: justice, mercy, and faithfulness. You should have practiced the latter, without neglecting the former.
V25, 26 - You clean the outside of the cup and dish, but inside they are full of greed and self-indulgence. Blind Pharisee! First clean the inside of the cup and dish, so that the outside may become clean as well.
V27, 28: You are like whitewashed tombs, which look beautiful on the outside, but on the inside are full of dead men’s bones and every kind of impurity. In the same way, on the outside you appear to be righteous, but on the inside you are full of hypocrisy and wickedness.

This gives the general idea.
That is, Jesus commended the teaching and keeping of the law as contained in the Torah.. What Jesus hated was all the religious "rubbish" piled on by the overly ostentatious and falsely "righteous" Pharisees.  They invented many rules never taught in the Torah.    Jesus taught the same thing in Matt 15:4-9 -

For God said, ‘Honor your father and mother’ and ‘Anyone who curses
his father or mother must be put to death.’ 5But you say that if
anyone says to his father or mother, ‘Whatever you would have received
from me is a gift devoted to God,’ he need not honor his father or
mother with it. Thus you nullify the word of God for the sake of your
tradition. You hypocrites! Isaiah prophesied correctly about you:
‘These people honor Me with their lips, but their hearts are far from
Me. They worship Me in vain; they teach as doctrine the precepts of
men.’”



According to the sentence of the law which they shall teach thee, and
according to the judgment which they shall tell thee, thou shalt do:
thou shalt not decline from the sentence which they shall shew thee,
to the right hand, nor to the left. And the man that will do
presumptuously, and will not hearken unto the priest that standeth to
minister there before the Lord thy God, or unto the judge, even that
man shall die: and thou shalt put away the evil from Israel. And all
the people shall hear, and fear, and do no more presumptuously. (Deut.
17:11-13)


The scribes and the Pharisees sit in Moses' seat: All therefore
whatsoever they bid you observe, that observe and do; but do not ye
after their works: for they say, and do not. (Matt. 23:2-3)

There are a lot of long-winded answers, but this isn't a complicated passage. Jesus was plainly telling them to obey the law. He's paraphrasing Deuteronomy almost word for word. What the priests teach, and what they say, do it, because they speak with the authority of Moses. But don't emulate their hypocrisy.

"Moses' seat" is a reference to the rabbinical doctrine of Oral Torah. The rabbis (most of whom at the time were part of the Pharisaic movement) were thought to be Moses' representatives, and their halakhic (legal) rulings were considered to have the same authority was the Torah itself. Some synagogues featured special throne-like chairs from which leading rabbis would issue judgments. In the Gospel of Matthew, Jesus upheld this authority, even though he sometimes disagreed with specific applications of it and denounced the Pharisees as hypocrites. In other words, even though Jesus struggled with the Pharisees, he still wanted his disciples to obey the leaders of their synagogues and accept the ruling of rabbinical courts.

We might think of this in the same vein as Paul's teaching in  Romans 13:1:

Let every person be subordinate to the higher
authorities, for there is no authority except from God, and those that
exist have been established by God.

Jesus' upholding Pharisaic authority is also consistent with his teaching in Mt. 5:

17 “Do not think that I have come to abolish the law or the prophets.
I have come not to abolish but to fulfill. 18 Amen, I say to you,
until heaven and earth pass away, not the smallest letter or the
smallest part of a letter will pass from the law, until all things
have taken place. 19 Therefore, whoever breaks one of the least of
these commandments and teaches others to do so will be called least in
the kingdom of heaven. But whoever obeys and teaches these
commandments will be called greatest in the kingdom of heaven. 20 I
tell you, unless your righteousness surpasses that of the scribes and
Pharisees, you will not enter into the kingdom of heaven.

Many of Jesus' disagreements with 'the Pharisees' may be seen as arguments among fellow rabbis about issues that were still open at the time. The School of Hillel was known to be less strict on many such issues, while the School of Shammai was more strict. Jesus would have agreed with the Hillelites on issues such as healing on the Sabbath and commerce with Gentiles, but he would have agreed with Shammai on divorce. But in a general sense, Jesus upheld the authority of Oral Torah. Indeed, in his own interpretation and expansion of the Law (see especially Mt. 5-6), Jesus practiced this very tradition.
Conclusion: The Gospel of Matthew portrays Jesus as upholding the Jewish doctrine of Oral Torah, in which rabbis/Pharisees issued authoritative pronouncements regarding the interpretation of the Mosaic law. This is the meaning of his reference to the "seat of Moses" and the authority of Pharisaic teaching. He debated his fellow rabbis about specific rulings, but taught his disciples to respect the pronouncement of local synagogue leaders generally.

I just have one problem with your reference to the meaning of "Moses' seat" as the doctrine of Oral Torah.  Moses' seat was where judgment was passed down to these scribes and Pharisees, not only orally, but by the 10 Commandments of God, written in stone, and which will be written in the minds and hearts in the new covenant (Heb. 8:10).
